# Snow Leopard keyboard mapping problem

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, keyboard-layout

[image][image]I've got a very weird problem, the mapping of my keyboard changed by itself to some weird layout like

- The caps lock light is on for lower case and off for upper case,
- All the keys are shuffled. For example <kbd>@</kbd> key went to the left of instead of <kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>

I am also providing the screen shot of the new mapping. I am also running Windows on bootcamp, and it was running ok with it before. It just changed suddenly, and I recently installed Xcode 4.

[image]

Comment: So which layout is selected in *Preferences - Language & Text - Input Sources*? Which one do you use normally? Can't you just set it back to the original one?

Comment: yeahh i tried that option but its not working for me at all !!

Comment: and i use 'US' normally ...

Comment: i ve also uploaded the screen shot of the input method please check

Comment: I'm sorry, for the moment I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Try removing the `HIToolbox` plist (`rm ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.HIToolbox*`).

Comment: i just restarted my pc and removed its battery in doing so it has started working fine again i dunno why... but thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved now: after a long day researching the issue I turned off the PC, removed the battery, inserted it again and turned on the PC - the problem is gone.

I'm still confused what exactly the problem was as you can see the in the screenshot that the mapping was disturbed. Curious if there was any hardware interference.